# Java identical recognition of objects

Tags: java, object, compare

So it seems that my java program is not able to recognize two identical objects even though I'm using the same method as in a previous question where java did recognize the two objects as being the same. The only difference in this program is I have an extra keyboard.nextLine() which is necessary for inputting the name/address of object two.

Here's the class input

```
    public boolean equals(Person num1) {
    if ((this.name==num1.name)&&(this.address==num1.address)&&
    (this.age==num1.age)&&(this.phoneNumber==num1.phoneNumber))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here's the demo input

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class PersonDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person num1, num2;
    num1=new Person();
    num2=new Person();

    String name, address;
    int age; 
    long phoneNumber;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input the name of person 1:");
    name=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the address of person 1:");
    address=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the age of person 1:");
    age=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input the phone number of person 1:");
    phoneNumber=keyboard.nextLong();
    keyboard.nextLine();

    num1.setName(name);
    num1.setAddress(address);
    num1.setAge(age);
    num1.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    System.out.println("\nInformation of person 1: ");
    System.out.println(num1);

    System.out.println("\nInput the name of person 2:");
    name=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the address of person 2:");
    address=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the age of person 2:");
    age=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input the phone number of person 2:");
    phoneNumber=keyboard.nextLong();

    num2.setName(name);
    num2.setAddress(address);
    num2.setAge(age);
    num2.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    System.out.println("\nInformation of person 2: ");
    System.out.println(num2);

    if (num1.equals(num2))
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 2 are identical.");
    else 
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 2 are not identical.");
}


   }
```

Comment: Why the `if` statement in the `equals` method? Just return the boolean...

Comment: if these thingies match then I return true :O

Comment: @user2514022 Yes, but just return "these thingies" instead of using an `if` statement. That's like saying `if (something) return true; else return false;` instead of just `return something`.

Comment: i can now close this question thank u

Answer (score 1):

For `Object(such as String)`, you need to use equals method. `==` only tests if these two Objects are the same objects (compare the memory address). In your case, `num1.name` and `num2.name` are different objects although the contents of them are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- not overriding Object.equals method correctly
- inside equals method, testing equality using ==, instead of equals
- not testing num1 for null

Do this:

```
@Overrides
public boolean equals(Object num1) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (num1 != null && num1 instanceof Person) {
        Person personNum1 = (Person)num1;
        result = this.name.equals(personNum1.name) &&
                 this.address.equals(personNum1.address) &&
                 this.age.equals(personNum1.age) && 
                 this.phoneNumber.equals(personNum1.phoneNumber);
    }
    return result;
}
```

BTW, any reasonable tutorial on equals would show this.  :)